# Socket object value is null

Tags: android, sockets

I'm having trouble using the sockets library.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class SocketAdapter{

    Socket mySocket=null;
    PrintWriter out=null;
    BufferedReader in=null;


    public SocketAdapter(String host,int port){


        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(host);

            mySocket = new Socket(serverAddr, port);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(mySocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mySocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void writeto(String data){
         out.println(data);
    }

    public String readdata(){

        String fromSocket=null;
        try {
            fromSocket = in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }// blocking 
        return fromSocket;

    }
    public void close(){

        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mySocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I access this class via a 2nd thread in my main activity. In the debugger the value of mySocket is always null. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong but I'm pretty sure its something basic.

EDIT: Turns out it the sockets object was null because of an IOException triggered by the app not having internet permission.

in the manifest fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much point in catching exceptions in constructors. It just misleads the rest of the code into assuming that the object has been completely constructed, when it hasn't. Change the constructor to *throw* those exceptions and remove all the try/catches, and catch the exceptions accordingly at the calling sites. Then you can never get a null Socket reference from this code again.

Answer (score 0):

use Socket variable as static may be it will work.
static Socket mySocket = null;

or 
use a separate function to get the socket Connection.

```
public Socket getSocketConnection(String strServerIP , int iPort) 
{
    try 
    {               
        Socket s = new Socket(strServerIP,iPort);  
        return s;
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {           
            return null;
    }
  }// End getSocketConnection Method.
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are working multiple threads, you need to be synchronized over the contractor.
You can implement it by your self or define the `SocketAdapter` class instance as [volotile](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml).

Also please read [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html)

Comment: Completely incorrect. Constructors do not need to be synchronized and indeed *cannot* be declared as `synchronized`. It doesn't even make sense. Each thread will be constructing its own instance, not the same instance. Declaring the `SocketAdapter` variable as volatile won't fix this problem either. -1.

Comment: @EJP No man you are wrong. The way to declare constructor as synchronized is using volatile. You should read the post I linked to.

Comment: @Babibyu (1) There is no such thing as a synchronized constructor, and no need for one whatsover. (2) Declaring a variable as `volatile` has no effect on the constructor of the object that is stored in it. (3) There is no indication in this posting that `volatile` is needed anywhere. (4) Your answer remains incorrect.

Comment: @EJP I don't agree with you, I added another link with better explanation for my point. Please give it a look.

Comment: If you are still asserting that constructors need to be synchronized, I have already explained why that belief is fallacious. Your new link about double checked locking is completely irrelevant to this question, as it isn't being attempted by the OP. You also have completely failed to explain how your answer accounts for the OP's problem. I also suggest you read my answer, and have a look at the big green tick next to it.